# Using .after to add a </tr><tr> is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a  `table` that currently has two columns per row and I need to split it using jQuery.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.TextBold').after('</tr><tr>');
});
```

...but it doesn't work. I wonder if can add a `<p>Test</p>` instead of `</tr><tr>` there?

Here you can see my code in JSFiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/QjJhU/

I will appreciate if someone can explain the issue.

Comment: You should be aware that in JavaScript, you don't add *tags*, like `'</tr><tr>'`. You only work with whole DOM elements.

Comment: this is new lesson for me thanks to all who replied here to my post!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are imagining that jQuery (and Javascript in general) edits the HTML document. It doesn't. The browser reads the HTML, then creates a DOM structure from it. At that point, the HTML content is utterly irrelevant. The only thing the browser cares about is the DOM structure.

This means that you can't add bits of elements: you can only add whole elements (or text nodes) to a document.  You're trying to close one tag (with `</tr>`) then open another one (with `<tr>`). In fact, the browser reads `</tr><tr>` and makes a DocumentFragment out of it. Since the closing tag is invalid on its own, it is removed. Then the `<tr>` is turned into an entire element in its own right: effectively, `<tr></tr>`. This is valid HTML, so it is turned into the valid DOM element and that is inserted.

You need to work out a way of removing the `td` from one `tr`, creating a new `tr` and adding the `td` to it.

Something like this should work:

```
$('.TextBold').each(function() {
    $('<tr/>').insertAfter(this.parentNode).append($(this).next());
});
```

This says:

- for each `TextBold` element, do the following:

  - create a new `tr` element
  - insert it after the `TextBold`'s parent element (which is the `tr`)
  - append the element that follows the `TextBold` to the new `tr` (this also has the effect of removing it from its current position)

[Here's a jsFiddle with this working code](http://jsfiddle.net/QjJhU/4/).

Answer (score 2):

Try instead:

```
$('.TextBold').each(
    function(){
        $('<tr />').insertAfter($(this).parent()).append($(this).next('td'));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QjJhU/2/).

The reason that your approach didn't work is because JavaScript, and therefore jQuery, creates DOM nodes, not mark-up as such. Therefore you can't add a closing `</tr>` and an opening `<tr>` tag, only a DOM node which comprises of the whole node.

As to your question:

> I wonder I can able to add a `<p>Test</p>` instead of `</tr><tr>` there.

I honestly can't work out quite what you mean; but inside of a `table`, and *outside* of a `td` or `th`, a `p` would render the mark-up invalid, as `p` is not a valid child of `tbody` , `tfoot`, `thead`, `tr` or `table`.

---

**Edited** to update the posted jQuery, to replace `parent()` with `closest()`:

```
$('.TextBold').each(
    function(){
        $('<tr />').insertAfter($(this).closest('tr')).append($(this).next('td'));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/QjJhU/7/).

References:

- [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: Glad to have been of help! =)